# meaning of the phrase "by spin"

Tags: meaning

What does "by spin" mean? Here it is in context:

> Be clear that what someone may label “complete, no-holds-barred honesty” may be just an excuse for verbally horse-whipping someone. Honesty doesn’t maim. Don’t be fooled by spin.

As far as I am concerned, "spin" means justification. Tell me please if I have a point there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Spin**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spin) is a relatively new, informal English term that came into use in the 1990s

> If someone puts a certain **spin** on an event or situation, they interpret it and try to present it in a particular way.

For example, Donald Trump has frequently *spun* stories of his alleged involvement with Russia during the election campaign, to suggest that these are "fake news" -- that the news organizations reporting these stories are just out to get him.

So "don't be fooled by spin" advises that you not be misled by the way someone may try to rephrase the facts in order to justify abuse.